# Execute a PHP call from Swift passing one parameter - does not work yet

Tags: swift

Trying to execute a call from Swift passing one parameter to PHP and getting the result

It does not execute the PHP call... not sure why?

```
    func getInfo(_ dataValue:String){

        print("in UserModel.getInfo")

        let url: URL = URL(string: urlInfoPath)!
        let rq = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)

        rq.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "a=\(dataValue)"
        rq.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        print("PHP postString:", postString)

        let defaultSession = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
        let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url) {
            data, response, error in

            print("UserModel.getINFO FROM PHP");

            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }

            let val = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            self.responseString = val! as String
            print("responseString = ", self.responseString)

        }
    }
```

Comment: "After you create the task, you must start it by calling its resume() method." https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1407613-datatask

Comment: using task.resume() That got it past the point of execution... but did I do something wrong in calling the PHP method? Seems to have no result? shows empty value for print("responseString = ", self.responseString)

Comment: Should I be able to test it by doing something like: http://website.com/info.php?a=1